# Cannot add Google account for Playstore, SSL not working

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I had Google Playstore installed on my Android 2.2 mobile. But unfortunately when I went to service centre the mobile was resetted to factory settings and all my data was lost.

Thereafter when I restarted my Internet, the default browser is unable to connect to any secured website. Even my news and weather is not getting connected. But the browser connects to other un-secured sites.

When I tried to reinstall Google play I was asked to add a Google account -- but it gave me an error that it cannot establish a secured connection.

No Google website except google.co.in is connected. However when I use the Opera mini browser I can visit any secured sites including GMail and Playstore.

But when I tried to download any apk from Google store it does not show any error in my PC but software is never downloaded. When I tried to use deviceID apk it is showing me nothing.

I think because I am unable to add any Google account the data file contains nothing.

Can anybody tell me how I can start secured connections in my default browser so that Google can connect to its secured server and I will be able to download from Play store?

Comment: To push an installation from the Googleplay website, your device must first be configured with the same account -- which explains why you never received any app this way. How did you "reinstall Google Play"? Was it no longer installed on your device?

Comment: My google account was  registered with Google and I was downloading software from play store before my mobile was taken to the service center and resetted for factory defaults. All the data was lost.  When I visit Google play storeeven now it shows me all old settings and even software I had downloaded prev. But now I can not add my account and get the rror reliable connection could not be established.

Comment: As your device has been reset either, have you tried another [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factory-reset)? If that doesn't solve the issue, you might need to return it to the service center again (talk to them first and explain your issue).

Answer (score -2):

Reset to current date, and I can definitely say a secure website will open.